# Can't update HTML element with Jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Working on a map application and this is driving me nuts. This works:

```
var myBounds = map.getBounds();
$("#bounds").html("My bounds are: " + myBounds);
```

But this just shows blank:

```
var myBounds = map.getBounds();
$("#bounds").html(myBounds);
```

No console errors in Chrome. It looks like Jquery doesn't like the return value of map.getBounds(), which in this case are Google map boundaries like ((34.71679866336405, -9.207592500000032), (38.42994070565381, -0.06696750000003249))

What is wrong here?

Update:
Curiously, this works OK too:

```
var myBounds2 = '((34.71679866336405, -9.207592500000032), (38.42994070565381, -0.06696750000003249))';
$("#bounds").html(myBounds2);
```

Comment: It's frequently useful with questions like this to include a **runnable**  [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button).

Comment: It looks like adding the text into .html() forces Jquery or JS to evaluate var myBounds?

Comment: The bit at the end of your question isn't curious; it would be curious if it *didn't* do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of [`getBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngBounds) isn't a string, it's a `LatLngBounds` object. Apparently passing the object directly into `html` doesn't work — which is fair enough, [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) doesn't document that it accepts objects, just strings. I'm a bit surprised it's not ending up calling `toString` on it, but apparently not.

Since converting it to string works (that's what you're doing when you append it to a string), you can do that by just passing into the `String` function:

```
var myBounds = map.getBounds();
$("#bounds").html(String(myBounds));
// ---------------^^^^^^^--------^
```

Comment: I'm surprised to see that as well, and also surprised that I haven't run into that issue myself. [It appears](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.html) the function accepts a string or an object that `append` can handle, which I suppose is either a DOM node or a jQuery object.

Comment: Yes it is surprising to also. I also thought that passing the return value of the object to a variable `var myBounds = map.getBounds();` would have automatically stringified it.

Comment: I accepted this answer but still it doesn't answer the question of why it works as expected when I also include some text in `.html()`, but not without?
`$("#bounds").html("My bounds are: " + myBounds);` OK
`$("#bounds").html(myBounds);` Not OK`

Comment: @silkfield: Yes, it does: `"My bounds are: " + myBounds` converts `myBounds` to string during the concatenation operation. That's what *"Since converting it to string works (that's what you're doing when you append it to a string)"* means.